# Expressible vs denotable values

Tags: functional-programming, programming-languages

What programming language has a value that is expressible but not denotable. Also what would this imply?
I don't really understand the difference. At the moment I think it means a functional language because then you can't give variables values only point to them?
Is this completely wrong?

Comment: I am glad that your question is brief but maybe too brief. Would you briefly also quote your source? It might help if we saw the usage in context. Using ">", you can quote like this: **> Veni, vidi, vici.**

Comment: Unfortunately, it's from an exam paper so there is no further information.

Comment: The actual answer was Java and wildcard generic types.  You can define an expression of a type but you cannot use a name to refer to that type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [these lecture notes](http://people.cs.ksu.edu/~schmidt/505f10/domainsS.html) by David Schmidt:

**Expressible values** are values that can be produced by expressions in code, like strings, numbers, lambdas/anonymous functions (in languages that support them), etc.

**Denotable values** are values that can be named (bound to an identifier) and referred to later, like values of variables or named functions.

For example, a language can have syntax for declaring named functions, but no expression syntax for anonymous functions. So (if I understand that correctly) in this language, functions would be *denotable but not expressible*.

The only example I could find of *values* that are *expressible but not denotable* are **error values** (in [some theoretical languages](https://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~cs4215/notes/notes_04.pdf#page=11) <sup>p.11</sup>), which can be produced by an expression (like `1/0`) but cannot be bound to an identifier (saved in a variable).
*(This assumes that the assignment statement propagates the error instead of simply storing the error value in the variable.)*

**Anonymous types** are also somewhat similar. For example in C#, you can define an anonymous object, which has an anonymous type that cannot be bound to an identifier (is not denotable):

```cs
// anonymous objects can only be saved into a variable by using type inference
var obj = new { Name = "Farah", Kind = "Human" };
```